# Is there a way to retrieve the type of an entry?

Tags: craft3

To be more specific, I would like to know if an entry is a Single or part of a Structure or Channel.

`entry.type` seems to return the name of the single or section.

Is there a way to retrieve this information for every entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure type is stored in the section, not in the entry type. `entry.type` doesn't return the name, it returns the entry type as an object

```
{% set structureType = entry.getSection().type %}
```

It will return a string that can have the following values.

```
const TYPE_SINGLE = 'single';
const TYPE_CHANNEL = 'channel';
const TYPE_STRUCTURE = 'structure';
```